# redirect url and change page after click event and serve html file to browser using GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I am trying to redirect localhost:9000 to localhost:9000/list after the user clicks on a button in home page and use a get method to display list.html. How can I use the AJAX call I have in display.js and the get request in my routes.js to redirect url and serve up my list.html. When I click on the button, nothing happens. To change url i tried both windows.location and location.href but I am not sure if these are even needed.

Directory layout

```
dir main
    -server.js
    dir subMain
      dir display
        -display.js
      dir routing
        -routes.js
      dir public
        -home.html
        -list.html
```

server.js

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('./subMain/routing/routes.js')(app, path, express);

app.listen(9000, function(){
     console.log('connected on 9000')
})
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, path, express){
    app.use(express.static("app"))
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/routing"));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/display"));
    app.use(function(request, response, next){
      response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/..", "public", "home.html"));
    })
    app.get('/list', function(request, response){
        response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/..', 'public', 'list.html'));
    });

}
```

display.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', sendSurvery);

function sendSurvery(){
    window.location = 'survey.html';
    //var myQueryUrl = "http://localhost:9000/survey";

    //$.ajax({url: myQueryUrl, method: 'GET', success: function(result){
        // location.href = "http://localhost:9000/list"

    //}}).done(function(response){

    //});
}
```

Update: Since AJAX is not required to change html on browser, where would be a suitable place to use the windows.location, and how would I connect that to a get request to my list.html? Right now, I tried doing a get request in both the server.js file and routes.js file, but when I click on the button, the url will change to survey but not the content on the browser (list.html is not displaying)

Update 2: I got rid of the AJAX call and just used: `windows.location = localhost:9000/list` but the get request is not sending the list.html file to the browser. I tried putting the get request in the server.js file also, but it still will do nothing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AJAX here (A stands for Asynchronous) - you can simply do `window.location = http://localhost:9000/survey`
This will effectively tell browser to send a synchronous GET request to the server and replace current page with whatever it receives as response.

Comment: I tried doing it without the AJAX but nothing happens. Where should I declare the window.location? In the routes.js file?

Comment: `window` is a global object available client-side (in browsers). It need not be initialized anywhere; you just need to change its value as stated in the answer.

Comment: So in my orignal post, I change it once the user clicks on a button in my display.js file, but the html file list.html wont show up on browser, it just stays at the home page

Comment: The assigned value to `window.location` should be a URL or URI. The client has no knowledge of what HTML files are available on the server. For example a valid assignment might be `window.location = '/some-url';`.

Comment: Yes I changed to what Igor mentioned and got rid of the AJAX request, but the html still does not display.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there is no survey.html in your listed tree structure....

also, if you want to do relative access, you may want to add a line similar to the below:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'subMain/public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

display.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', sendSurvery);

function sendSurvery(){
    var myQueryUrl = "http://localhost:9000/";
    window.location.replace(myQueryUrl + 'survey.html)
}
```

This would allow you to actually store `myQueryUrl` as a config variable elsewhere so that it could be changed based on your environment.

You also have to make sure that you link to display.js in your html file so it's initially requested from the server. The server won't just send it for you.

And you don't show the rest of your file but you might need to initializing the call to the click handler if you aren't doing that:

```
(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#btn', sendSurvery);
}();
```

As a note, `GET` requests (and all requests for that matter) originate on the *Client* and are sent to the server. So they must be placed in files being sent to the client.